# How do I get validation errors from within a form group

Tags: vue-formulate

When using Vue Formulate, if you have a form group with nested form fields, how do you get the errors on those form fields?

If I bind a handler to the parent form, like this:

```js
<formulate-input @validation="myValidationEvent"> ...
```

If I log the output from that event to the console, the output for a normal form field looks this this:

```
{name: 'personalDetails', errors: Array(1), hasErrors: true}
```

where `errors` is an array containing the errors. But if I do the same for a form group, I get this:

```
{name: 'personalDetails', errors: Array(0), hasErrors: true}
```

Note the empty `errors` array. **How do I get to the errors on the form fields nested inside the group?**

Thanks!